# Free - SP16 buffer

Tags: c

I have this buffer:

```
SP16 audio_data[4000]; //Typershort SP16
```

And it will be filled with audio samples:

```
memcpy(audio_data, global_data, size_chunck);
```

But if I do `free(audio_data[4000])` I will trigger a breakpoint, so I will get an error. Why?

Comment: Read **carefully**: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you may only `free()` memory obtained via `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

Comment: How can I clean up such variable? @glglgl

Comment: @jdscardoso By not creating it. Once you have it, you have it. That's why this kind of allocation is called "static allocation" as opposed to "dynamic allocation" via the heap (malloc, free, ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you `free` memory not allocated by `malloc` or similar your program may cause error.

Your variable is not allocated using `malloc` or similar so there is no need to `free` it .

From C99 standard -

> 7.22.3.3 The free function
>
> 2. [...]Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.